# How can I remove certain email addresses for someone in a Gmail contact group?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, contacts-group

I just created a group based on an email which worked great but I am trying to figure out how to remove multiple email addresses per person (just within this group list). The issue I have is that there were some duplicates so when I look at the group in Gmail, there are a few names that have a (+1) or (+2) next to the email address (meaning that a single person has multiple email addresses on this group)

As an example, lets say I have a contact name Joe Simpson.  He has two email addresses: **Joe@work.com** and **Joe@home.com**. In the Group **MyNewGroup**, both email addresses are listed so when I look at that group I see Joe Simpson listed there with one of the emails and a (+1) next to the email. 
I only want to have this group send to **Joe@home.com** but I don't want to delete the fact that Joe also has this work account.

How can I remove an email address for a person from the group without actually deleting the email address for the person in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a contact to a group you choose the email address that you want to add to it and not the actual contact.

When the contact are displayed in the group list you will have the email you have chosen and +x depending on how many other email address the person has, however, when you send an email to that group it will be *only* sent to the email address you have added to the group, not all the emails belonging to the contact.

Comment: This is now so wildly inaccurate, given the multiple changes made by Google, that I suggest the thread is archived as nothing in it is now true.